# Recuperar dados de outros fragments ao clicar em botão?

Tags: android, fragment

Tenho um formulário com 3 Fragments, onde no ultimo há um botão de salvar, quando clico neste botão preciso pegar os dados inseridos pelo usuário no Fragment 1 e 2, obter os dados do fragment aberto (3) e salvar, para isso pensei em usar Singleton onde tenho um classe modelo que contem todos os valores dos inputs, porem não sei como salvar os dados neste singleton quando saio(Swipe ou clique em outro fragment na TabLayout) do Fragment 1 e 2. Alguem me sugere alguma solução por favor.

Função de salvar dados na Activity atraves da interface do fragment "A":

```
@Override
public void salvarDadosPessoais(HashMap<String, Object> hashMap) {
    paciente.setNOME(hashMap.get("nome").toString());
    paciente.setDATA_NASC(Utils.obterInstancia().StringToDate(hashMap.get("dataNasc").toString()));
    paciente.setSEXO(hashMap.get("sexo").toString());
    paciente.setTIPO_SANGUINEO(Integer.parseInt(hashMap.get("tipoSanguineo").toString()));
    paciente.setNOME_MAE(hashMap.get("nomeMae").toString());
    paciente.setDESCONHECE_NOME_PAI(Integer.parseInt(hashMap.get("desconhecePai").toString()));
    paciente.setNOME_PAI(hashMap.get("nomePai").toString());
    paciente.setEMAIL(hashMap.get("email").toString());
    paciente.setSTATUS_NACIONALIDADE(Integer.parseInt(hashMap.get("statusNacionalidade").toString()));
    paciente.setNATURALIDADE(hashMap.get("naturalidade").toString());
    paciente.setCODIGO_DOCUMENTO(Integer.parseInt(hashMap.get("codigoDocumento").toString()));
    paciente.setDATA_NATURALIZACAO(Utils.obterInstancia().StringToDate(hashMap.get("dataNaturalizacao").toString()));
    paciente.setPORTARIA_NATURALIZACAO(hashMap.get("portariaNaturalizacao").toString());
    paciente.setDATA_ENTRADA_BRASIL(Utils.obterInstancia().StringToDate(hashMap.get("dataEntradaBrasil").toString()));
    paciente.setCODIGO_UF_NATURALIDADE(hashMap.get("codigoUfNaturalidade").toString());
    paciente.setCODIGO_DOCUMENTO(Integer.parseInt(hashMap.get("codigoDocumento").toString()));
    paciente.setDOCUMENTO(hashMap.get("documento").toString());
    paciente.setCNS(hashMap.get("cns").toString());
    paciente.setPRONTUARIO(hashMap.get("prontuario").toString());
    paciente.setCPF(hashMap.get("cpf").toString());
    paciente.setRG(hashMap.get("rg").toString());
    paciente.setCTPS(hashMap.get("ctps").toString());
    paciente.setCODIGO_RACA_COR(Integer.parseInt(hashMap.get("racaCor").toString()));
}
```

Função que gera o HashMap para enviar para a activity:

```
public HashMap<String, Object> persistTransients() {
    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("nome", cadNome.getText().toString());
    hashMap.put("dataNasc", splitReverseJoin(cadDataNasc.getText().toString()));
    hashMap.put("sexo", rootView.findViewById(cadRadGroupSexo.getCheckedRadioButtonId()).getTag().toString());
    Integer tipoSanguineo =  cadTipoSanguineo.getSelectedItemPosition();
    hashMap.put("tipoSanguineo", getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Tipo_Sanguineo_Value)[tipoSanguineo]);
    hashMap.put("nomeMae", cadNomeMae.getText().toString());
    if(cadChkDescPai.isChecked()){
        hashMap.put("desconhecePai", 1);
    }else{
        hashMap.put("desconhecePai", 0);
    }
    hashMap.put("nomePai", cadNomePai.getText().toString());
    hashMap.put("email", cadEmail.getText().toString());
    hashMap.put("statusNacionalidade", rootView.findViewById(cadRadGroupNac.getCheckedRadioButtonId()).getTag());
    hashMap.put("naturalidade", cadMunicipioNasc.getTag().toString());
    Integer paisN = cadPaisNasc.getSelectedItemPosition();
    hashMap.put("codigoDocumento", getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Pais_Nasc_Value)[paisN]);
    hashMap.put("dataNaturalizacao", splitReverseJoin(cadDataNatur.getText().toString()));
    hashMap.put("portariaNaturalizacao", cadPortariaNatu.getText().toString());
    hashMap.put("dataEntradaBrasil", Utils.obterInstancia().StringToDate(splitReverseJoin(cadDataEntrada.getText().toString())));
    Integer estado = cadEstado.getSelectedItemPosition();
    hashMap.put("codigoUfNaturalidade", getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Estados_Value)[estado]);
    Integer tipoDoc = cadTipoDoc.getSelectedItemPosition();
    hashMap.put("codigoDocumento", getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Tipo_Documento_Value)[tipoDoc]);
    hashMap.put("documento", cadDocumento.getText().toString());
    hashMap.put("cns", cadCns.getText().toString());
    hashMap.put("prontuario", cadProntuario.getText().toString());
    hashMap.put("cpf", cadCpf.getText().toString());
    hashMap.put("rg", cadRg.getText().toString());
    hashMap.put("ctps", cadCtps.getText().toString());
    Integer racaCor = cadRacaCor.getSelectedItemPosition();
    hashMap.put("racaCor", getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Raca_Cor_Value)[racaCor]);
    return hashMap;
}
```

Comment: Se você vai utilizar essas informações, fornecidas pelo usuário. Seria melhor, armazená-las localmente? Dependendo da quantidade de informações sugiro o SQLite, porém vc tem mais [opções de armazenamento](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage?hl=pt-br).

Comment: Sim, onde eu digo salvar é enviar para o banco local SQLite, porem pra eu poder enviar para o banco local eu preciso das informações de todos os fragments e não sei como faço pra recuperar as informações dos fragments que não estão ativos.

Comment: Pelo que entendi, vc ainda não criou um database do SQLite, correto. Caso não, existem alguns tutoriais de como fazê-lo. Vc pode ler mais neste [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage?hl=pt-br#db). Se vc já tem um database criado, vc pode salvar os dados a cada vez que vc muda de Fragment. Ou vc, poderia enviar tudo através de uma interface, mas isso depende de como vc está construindo sua aplicação. Se puder compatilhar o que vc tem pronto até então...

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta, necessariamente eu preciso de um metodo para reconhecer quando o fragment será trocado e chamar o metodo da activity para salvar os dados do fragment na minha Classe Singleton, quando eu tiver os 3 fragments completos eu terei o meu Objeto Singleton completo e poderei salvar no banco SQLite com todas as informações corretamente.